# UNIX Shell Script IP Lookup

Tags: linux, unix

UNIX/LINUX:
I'm not there yet with writing shell scripts. Trying to write a short shell script that asks user to input IP address and performs host lookup of IP address and returns a name if available:

```
echo -n "Enter IP address"
read IP
echo -n "Your IP adress is" $IP
nslookup IP
```

*should i use nslookup or ping a?

Answer (score 2):

> should i use nslookup or ping a

Neither, you should use [dig](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dig).

```
dig  +short -x 8.8.8.8
google-public-dns-a.google.com.
```

You could use [host](http://linux.die.net/man/1/host) too

The nslookup program is deprecated and should not be relied upon.

Comment: Actually it's `dig +short -x 8.8.8.8`

Comment: So why didn't you or the person who upvoted your comment fix it ?

Comment: Sorry, new to serverfault, still learning how to use it :)

Comment: so,  dig -x IP +short would do the trick?